# no .gitmodules in my repo but src directory appears zipped like a submodule

Tags: git

I have been following many answers on SO for similar questions but I am still fuzzy on it. I just got access to a repo that wasn't in use for around 4 months. So, I have to create a repo of it to my machine. It is Angular 5 project.

It does clone it but it doesn't clone the "src" directory of the project. The src directory have zip icon in the repo's master branch with @ d1d70b82 on the side. The previous developer who worked on the project don't remember doing anything to the directory and that the .git existed only on the main project.

Regardless, I want to get contents of the src directory as they are. I couldn't find file .gitmodules in the cloned repo. My config looks like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://gitlab.com/ss/rfe.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[submodule "src"]
    active = true
    url = https://gitlab.com/ss/rfe
```

Doing:

```
git ls-files --stage | grep 160000
```

gives:

```
160000 d1d70b82557761951d9e7b9d39e3a11a94a06147 0       src
```

I have seen tips on how to go ahead but am afraid of corrupting the src and lose the code base.

How do I unlock or clone the src directory please

Comment: Did you clone with `--recurse-submodules`? If not, run `git submodule update --init`.

Comment: @o11c i just did git clone with --recurse-submodules first and the src directory is empty after cloning. Then I tried the update --init but it made no difference. Did i run them right?

Comment: Hm, that's odd - in the config you pasted, you have the *same* URL for `origin` as you do for the submodule. That's not how submodules normally work.

Comment: Oh thanks @o11c. I guess it is lost cause then.